# What would be the fastest way to remove Newlines from a String in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a string that has some Environment.Newline in it. I'd like to strip those from the string and instead, replace the Newline with something like a comma.

What would be, in your opinion, the best way to do this using C#.NET 2.0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not:

```
string s = "foobar\ngork";
string v = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine,",");
System.Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
string s = "hello\nworld";
s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string sample = "abc" + Environment.NewLine + "def";
string replaced = sample.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel — just use:

```cs
myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is the builtin way: Use `string.Replace`. Why do you need alternatives?