# How to remove the linefeed or newline from a text file or cdr file including the spaces?

Tags: c#

This is my situation, I was able to remove the spaces using trim or replace. But it does not remove the linefeed or newline at the end of each file. How can I remove the spaces and linefeed in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the file in a string buffer? And do you want to remove whitespace and newlines/linefeed characters at the end of the file or at the end of every line?

Comment: It would *really* help to see your code. It's pretty much impossible to diagnose what's wrong without seeing it.

Answer (score 6):

You can call Trim method with all characters that you want to be removed like:

```
line = line.Trim(' ','\r','\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = myString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)
myString = myString.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Alternately, use:

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(s, @" |\t|\n|\r", string.Empty);
```

For Line Feeds and New Lines:

```
myString = myString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "replacement text")
```

For Spaces:

```
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "replacement text");
```

Reference:

1. [StackOverFlow Link - System.Environment.NewLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)
2. [StackOverFlow Link - Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140723/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-a-string)