# How to remove new line characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string in the following format

```
string s = "This is a Test String.\n   This is a next line.\t This is a tab.\n'
```

I want to remove all the occurrences of `\n` and `\r` from the string above.

I have tried `string s = s.Trim(new char[] {'\n', '\r'});` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

I like to use regular expressions. In this case you could do:

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(s, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

Regular expressions aren't as popular in the .NET world as they are in the dynamic languages, but they provide a lot of power to manipulate strings.

Comment: This was definitely the best solution for me. A smooth blend of this C# and javascript was all I needed to resolve my issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I needed also to remove newlines from my string. I tried to do it with string.Replace, didn't work. When I used Regex.Replace with the exact same regular expression string as the parameter, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful if using this in a loop that processes 1M+ items.  Regex is way slower than just String.Replace

Comment: The code example also removes tabs \t, which is not in question.

Answer (score 86):

You want to use `String.Replace` to remove a character.

```
s = s.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
s = s.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
s = s.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
```

Note that `String.Trim(params char[] trimChars)` only removes leading and trailing characters in `trimChars` from the instance invoked on.

You could make an extension method, which avoids the performance problems of the above of making lots of temporary strings:

```
static string RemoveChars(this string s, params char[] removeChars) {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(s != null);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(removeChars != null);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    foreach(char c in s) { 
        if(!removeChars.Contains(c)) {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach will create two intermediate string objects.  Depending on the size of your string, this could have significant performance and memory consumption consequences.

Answer (score 49):

I know this is an old post, however I thought I'd share the method I use to remove new line characters.

```
s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

*References:*

[MSDN String.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) and [MSDN Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Comment: nice for Mono support

Comment: In cross-environment (i.e. Windows app that is feed with data from Unix system) application this will cause more problems than profits.

Answer (score 18):

If speed and low memory usage are important, do something like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);

foreach (char i in s)
    if (i != '\n' && i != '\r' && i != '\t')
        sb.Append(i);

s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, i'd go with this too (in an extension method). Always good to use StringBuilder. +1

Comment: "Always good to use the StringBuilder" < I'm no pro, but that's not strictly true.  This [article by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) provides a fun insight into string manipulation/concatenation and ultimately, optimisation.

Answer (score 5):

just do that

```
s = s.Replace("\n", String.Empty).Replace("\t", String.Empty).Replace("\r", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

A LINQ approach:

```
string s = "This is a Test String.\n   This is a next line.\t This is a tab.\n'";

string s1 = String.Join("", s.Where(c => c != '\n' && c != '\r' && c != '\t'));
```

Comment: This is using the generic overload of `string.Join` that will call `ToString` on each `char` returned by the query.  Better to just pass the query results to the `string` constructor.  `s1 = new string(s.Where(....).ToArrary());`

Answer (score 2):

The right choice really depends on how big the input string is and what the perforce and memory requirement are, but I would use a regular expression like

```
string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\r\n?|\n|\t", String.Empty);
```

Or if we need to apply the same replacement multiple times, it is better to use a compiled version for the Regex like

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\r\n?|\n|\t", RegexOptions.Compiled); 
string result = regex.Replace(s, String.Empty);
```

NOTE: different scenarios requite different approaches to achieve the best performance and the minimum memory consumption

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using [`ReplaceLineEndings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replacelineendings) since .NET 6:

> This method searches for all newline sequences within the string and canonicalizes them to the newline sequence provided by replacementText. If replacementText is [Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty), all newline sequences within the string will be removed.

Note that it supports multiple types of newline sequences:

> The list of recognized newline sequences is CR (U+000D), LF (U+000A), CRLF (U+000D U+000A), NEL (U+0085), LS (U+2028), FF (U+000C), and PS (U+2029). This list is given by the Unicode Standard, Sec. 5.8, Recommendation R4 and Table 5-2.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I would like you to understand more specific areas of space. `\t` is actually assorted as a horizontal space, not a vertical space. (test out inserting `\t` in Notepad)

If you use Java, simply use `\v`. See the reference below.

> `\h` - A horizontal whitespace character:
>
> `[\t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`
>
> `\v` - A vertical whitespace character:
>
> `[\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]`

But I am aware that you use .NET. So my answer to replacing every vertical space is..

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\n\u000B\u000C\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]", "");
```

Comment: It looks like an answer to some other question... and also missing actual reference...

Answer (score 0):

```
string remove = Regex.Replace(txtsp.Value).ToUpper(), @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

Comment: Would be great if your answer had more explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -4):

You can use `Trim` if you want to remove from start and end.

```
string stringWithoutNewLine = "\n\nHello\n\n".Trim();
```

Answer (score -6):

FYI,

Trim() does that already.

The following LINQPad sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var s = " \rsdsdsdsd\nsadasdasd\r\n ";
    s.Length.Dump();
    s.Trim().Length.Dump();
}
```

Outputs:

```
23
18
```

Comment: That doesn't remove the \n in the middle.