# Regex to remove \n\ from a string in C# (Not \n)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am looking for a 'Regex' to replace `\n\` from my string. I already looked thorough this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140723/how-to-remove-new-line-characters-from-a-string) and other regex posts here, but in my case I need to remove the value `\n\` from a string not a new line or (`\n`).

For example:

```
string eneteredString = @"abc\n\def\n\ghi\n\\";
```

Here `\\` can be found multiple times too.

I have already tried Replacing `Enviornment.NewLine`, as it is not a new line in my case, it also didn't work. When I try below code,

```
string regout = Regex.Replace(enteredString, @"\n\","");
```

It says parsing `"\n\" - Illegal \ at the end of pattern` . Can you anyone please help me with the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"\\n\\"`  escape the `escape` character

Comment: Use a mere String.Replace. `eneteredString.Replace(@"\n\", "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but if I use `String.Replace`  it will be removing only one occurrence right?

Comment: @SibeeshVenu: Where did you get it from? String.Replace replaces all occurrences. This is not JavaScript.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks much, I totally lost my control, thanks much for the light. What I was doing is, checking the value of `eneteredString` after the statement `eneteredString.Replace(@"\n\", "")` instead of assigning that value to some other string variable and check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Who need regex?

```
string regout = @"abc\n\def\n\ghi\n\\".Replace(@"\n\", "");
```

And just because quotes are cool, [here is the famous](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: `regout` is just a lie now :)

Comment: @CyrilGandon Thanks, but if I use `String.Replace` it will be removing only one occurrence right?

Comment: nop, every occurence will be replaced, see @RajshekarReddy screenshot  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41264492/128662

Comment: @CyrilGandon Thanks much, I totally lost my control, thanks much for the light. What I was doing is, checking the value of `eneteredString` after the statement `eneteredString.Replace(@"\n\", "")` instead of assigning that value to some other string variable and check.

Comment: @CyrilGandon Just curious to know, what if I need to add the values we get after the `Replace` to a `List`? Can we do that without looping through?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Adding the string to a List<string>? maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

use `@"\\n\\"` . You need to remove the meaning of the escape character `\` by adding a `\` before it.. Here is a testing image

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the light.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu glad to help.. :)

Comment: Just curious to know, what if I need to add the values we get after the Replace to a List? Can we do that without looping through?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. The reason is due to how regex handles the single \

```
string regout = Regex.Replace(enteredString, @"\\n\\","");
```

Comment: No, with @, it's not the compiler, it's the Regex who's responsible for that behavior