# Show new lines from text area in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, text

I'm currently creating an application using ASP.NET MVC. I got some user input inside a textarea and I want to show this text with <br />s instead of newlines. In PHP there's a function called nl2br, that does exactly this. I searched the web for equivalents in ASP.NET/C#, but didn't find a solution that works for me.

The fist one is this (doesn't do anything for me, comments are just printed without new lines):

```
<%
    string comment = Html.Encode(Model.Comment);
    comment.Replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n");
%>
<%= comment %>
```

The second one I found was this (Visual Studio tells me VbCrLf is not available in this context - I tried it in Views and Controllers):

```
<%
    string comment = Html.Encode(Model.Comment);
    comment.Replace(VbCrLf, "<br />");
%>
<%= comment %>
```

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks are really "\r\n", and not just "\n", "\r" or "\n\r"?

Comment: As far as I know, in the Windows world line breaks are \r\n ;) - but I tried with just \n too, didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try (not tested myself):

```
comment = comment.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

**UPDATED:**

Just tested the code - it works on my machine

**UPDATED:**

Another solution:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(originalString);
string tmpS = null;
do {
    tmpS = sr.ReadLine();
    if (tmpS != null) {
        sb.Append(tmpS);
        sb.Append("<br />");
    }
} while (tmpS != null);
var convertedString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: System.Environment.NewLine refers to the server's environment, no? Would this work if the client's browser was a different environment?

Comment: I had this same problem.  The first solution fixed it for one of my text areas. but I needed to use a char(10)  for one of the others.  the only difference was one was submitted ajaxly and the other normally.  just thought i'd add this incase someone else had the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

to view html tags like a `DisplayFor`

you need to use another method , in fact the mvc dosent allowed you to view tags in page

but you can used this to ignore this option

```
@Html.Raw(model => model.text)
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Razor-based view , string with line breaks and want to show that text with the line-breaks intact in your view, you can do this without replacing all \r\n with "html br"-tags. Instead present the text in an element that has the style property white-space set to pre-line. You should really add a class like:

```
<span class="line-breaks">@Model.MyText</span>


    .line-breaks {
 white-space:pre-line;
 }
```

Original Found @

https://kaliko.com/blog/text-line-breaks-in-asp.net-mvc-razor-view/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look this answer [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c) here.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Raw(@Model.Comment.RestoreFormatting())

and than...

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string RestoreFormatting(this string str)
    {
        return str.Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and above all answer given the hint, not exactly help, that's why given the answer to help.

Replace "\n" strign with '
', '\r\n','\n', nothing help and finally when replace  "\r\n", it will work. (in display it like `\n`, but in database it store as `\\n`)

**Old code**

```
 @Html.TextArea("MEPat_textPatNote", Model.MedicationPatCur, 4, 4, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 100%;", maxlength = "300" })
```

[image]

**New code**

```
 @Html.TextArea("MEPat_textPatNote", Model.MedicationPatCur.PatNote== null? "": Model.MedicationPatCur.PatNote.Replace("\\n","\r\n"), 4, 4, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 100%;", maxlength = "300" })
```

[image]