# ASP.Net MVC - Displaying text with newlines in

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, text-formatting

I have some text, stored in a table.
I'm using asp.net mvc to display this.

One of my views, has the following:

```
<%=(Model.QuestionBody.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace ("\r", "<br/>")) %>
```

Like this, it displays correctly
However, if I omit the .Replace, it displays all on one line.

The same data displayed in a TextBox however, displays properly formatted.

My question is-
Is there a better way of displaying the text in my View?

Comment: This is really an HTML question, not a ASP.NET question

Comment: @gustavogb: It's an ASP.NET MVC question.  I added the HTML tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your text in a "pre" tag.

```
<pre>
   <%= Model.QuestionBody %>
</pre>
```

However usually this kind of text is stored in the database as html including the 
 tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967087/show-new-lines-from-text-area-in-asp-net-mvc) is the same issue  isn't it? If so, solution could be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Best method... No conversions...

```
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Show formatted text";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="h3">
    <span style="white-space: pre-wrap">@Model.myText</span>
  </div>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this is a handy dandy extention method i use to format strings with new lines.  it's in vb, so if your a c# type person it'll neeed some tweaking. but it works and keeps the views tidy.

```
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function FormatForDisplay(ByVal stringToFormat As String) As String

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToFormat) Then

                stringToFormat = Replace(stringToFormat, vbCrLf, "<br />")
                stringToFormat = Replace(stringToFormat, vbCr, "<br />")
                stringToFormat = Replace(stringToFormat, vbLf, "<br />")
                Return stringToFormat
            End If

            Return stringToFormat

        End Function
```

so then in your view you would have:

```
<%=(Model.QuestionBody.FormatForDisplay()) %>
```