# How to show a new line (<br>) with LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a TextArea where a user can write some text. When i try to show the text with LabelFor, i get an "illegal characters" error, because it the string has "\r\n" for every new line.

I've tried to use this solution:

[Show new lines from text area in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967087/show-new-lines-from-text-area-in-asp-net-mvc)

and

```
     if (q.help_text != null)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(q.help_text);

            string tmpS = null;
            do
            {
                tmpS = sr.ReadLine();
                if (tmpS != null)
                {
                    sb.Append(tmpS);
                    sb.Append("<br />");
                }
            } while (tmpS != null);
            var convertedString = sb.ToString();
            qvm.HelpText = convertedString;
        }
        else
            qvm.HelpText = q.help_text;
```

Instead of making new lines, LabelFor outputs the br code as well. 
How can i solve this?

**EDIT**

The solution was to do it this way:

@Html.Raw("

"+question.HelpText+"

Comment: Please be aware with Cross Site scripting issue in case you choose to use the answer you have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax for LabelFor

```
@Html.Raw(Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name))
```

Comment: Html.LabelFor returns MvcHtmlString, Html.Raw takes string as parameter. If i do: <td>@Html.Raw(@Html.LabelFor(y=>question.HelpText, question.HelpText).ToString())</td> it returns the same result as LabelFor

Comment: I just tested your method with my code and it outputs the same result as LabelFor, it doesnt show new lines :/

Comment: @Html.Raw("<p>"+question.HelpText+"</p") was the solution. You were closest.

Answer (score 3):

This is because LabelFor is HTML encoding the text . This is done to avoid cross site scripting issues. What you can do is use `pre` tag to render the text area string as it is (with \r\n)

Comment: Can you provide an example please

Comment: Something like `@Html.Raw("<pre>" + help_text + "</pre>")` . NOTE: You don't need to replace \r\n with <br> in `help_text`

Comment: I just tested this, it does show new lines. BUT it stretches my <td> so it doesnt fit the screen. Also, the text formatting is not the same as the rest :/