# Replace newlines with <p> paragraph and with <br /> tags

Tags: c#, .net, html, string, newline

So I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c) how to replace newlines in my C# code. But replacing a newline for a `<br />` tag isn't always very correct.

So I was wondering what kind of strategy do others use? The correct way I guess would be to use `<p>` tags and `<br />` tags.

Here are some examples of the results I would like to get.

If there is no newline I want the text to wrapped in a `<p>` tags.

> This text contains no newlines

```
<p>This text contains no newlines</p>
```

If the text contains a newline I want it to be replaced by a `<br />` tag and be wrapped in `<p>` tags.

> This text contains
>   1 newline

```
<p>This text contains<br /> 1 newline.</p>
```

If there are 'double newlines' I want that block to be wrapped in `<p>` tags.

> This is a text with 'double newlines' at the end.
>
> This is a text with no newline at the end.

```
<p>This a text with 'double newlines at the end.</p>
<p>This is a text with no newline at the end.</p>
```

I could write more examples/combination but I guess it's somewhat clear what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it using only simple string replacements:

```
    string result = "<p>" + text
        .Replace(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, "</p><p>")
        .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
        .Replace("</p><p>", "</p>" + Environment.NewLine + "<p>") + "</p>";
```

Note that your text must be HTML-escaped first otherwise you could be at risk of cross-site scripting attacks. (Note: even using `<pre>` tags still has a cross-site scripting risk).

Comment: Nice solution. I had something that looked a little like this but yours is a lot better.

Comment: Note that if you're expecting text that could come from another OS you'll want to consider not only replacing Environment.NewLine but other kinds of newLine characters.  See some of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp.

Comment: Late to the party, but this worked great for me: https://gist.github.com/plioi/5971498

Comment: Thank you @DerekHunziker your solution worked fantastic. Since, I am importing the data from a WordPress, it worked very good. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You could just leave it alone and use CSS to render the breaks correctly.  Here is a complicated example that is a kind of "pretty" replacement for the <pre> but you are using a <p> instead:

<p style="padding: 1em; line-height: 1.1em; font-family: monospace; white-space: pre; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(240,255,240); border: thin solid rgb(255,220,255);">

Text goes here.

</p>

Comment: You shouldn't always use <p> instead of <br />. It's mostly correct but not always.

Comment: I think most people want to use the white-space:pre-wrap; property. It wraps your lines, but still shows the text as paragraphs.