# Add <br> or paragraph in Textarea Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using textbox for allowing user  to enter any text they want, then I am emailing this text.
I want to add paragraphs or 
 in textarea text
for eg if user enters this

```
this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test
this is test this is test this is test this is test this is test
```

Then the email wil appear with whole text in one line, I want it to appear like two or three paragraphs
something like this

```
<p> this is test this is test this is test </p>
<p> this is test this is test this is test </p>
```

How I can do this in C#

Comment: I bet this covers all your needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015563/replace-newlines-with-p-paragraph-and-with-br-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textarea `\n` added on pressing of Enter key. replace `\n` with `<br/>` on server side.

Comment: How can I do that? I can't ask user to enter \n

Comment: when user press Enter key \n added into textarea string