# Using C# to convert incorrect html string to real html

Tags: c#, html, string, replace

My original issue is that I am trying to serialize a string containing html tags to an XML element.

```
hello <a href="world.php">World</a>, this

is
a nice
test

<ul>
  <li>to demonstrate my issue</li>
  <li>and find a solution</li>
</ul>
```

However, I have 2 issues

1. Serializing HTML to XML: I did not succeed in defining the Serializable class to correctly serialize with XmlSerialze, so I decided that, using CDATA sections might be the better way. This is however not correctly deserialized by the target tool (that I have no influence on). What I need is plain and correct html (XHMTL?) within the xml output file.

---

2. The string looks e.g. as above, but is not fully correct html (no `<p>` tags,  no `<br>` tags).
Now I would like to replace the newlines by a p or br tag. I have had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015563/replace-newlines-with-p-paragraph-and-with-br-tags) and used the suggested solution:

```
    string result = "<p>" + text
     .Replace(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, "</p><p>")
     .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
     .Replace("</p><p>", "</p>" + Environment.NewLine + "<p>") + "</p>";
```

However, this does not in all cases generate valid html. In the example above, it would create `<br />`s between the `<li>` tags or cause `<ul>` tags within `<p>` tags - which is both not allowed.

Target would be to have a result like the following (line breaks are only for better readability and don't matter here)

```
<p>hello <a href="world.php">World</a>, this</p>
<p>is<br/>
a nice<br/>
test<br/></p>
<ul>
  <li>to demonstrate my issue</li>
  <li>and find a solution</li>
</ul>
```

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this either with a string.Replace, Regex, or better solution (HtmlDocument)?

Please note: I have no influence on deserialization, the XML output is evaluated by I tool I have no influence on, and it has to be UTF-8 encoded.

Thank you!

EDIT: Clearly separated the 2 issues

EDIT2: No influence on deserialization

EDIT3: Added target output

Comment: How about html encode?

Comment: Is your question _"How can I transport HTML inside XML"_, or _"How to make valid HTML from invalid HTML"_? Or "whichever is easier"?

Comment: Valid question, actually both but with more priority on the 2nd. I have separated the 2 topics above

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is implement a ["tag soup parser"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), which takes text that may or may not be HTML as input and transforms that into a valid DOM, that a HTML parser can handle.

You don't want to reinvent this wheel, most definitely not with simple string replaces. See [How to parse bad html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720961/how-to-parse-bad-html) for some hints.

---

Or you can just encode the input HTML in such a way that it doesn't interfere with the XML that you're trying to put it in, [like a CDATA section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978316/how-do-i-store-html-page-in-a-xml-file) or [base64-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32439111/266143) the input would also suffice. Don't use "entity encoding", as your XML parser is going to complain about HTML entities that aren't XML entities.

Comment: Here the HtmlAgilityPack is mentioned, however I can't find any proper documentation. Does it provide a way to correct unallowed sequences or nestings (e.g. ul within p or br within ul)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do similar (ensuring 3rd party content has valid HTML).  If I was doing this, I'd do the following:

1)  Replace line breaks with HTML line breaks

```
string result = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

2) Use the HTMLAgility pack to fix any invalid HTML

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
    doc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
    doc.LoadHtml(result);

    if (doc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
    {
                // throw error
    }else{
                // get fixed html
                 result= doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```

Comment: This does not fully solve my issue: 1. This does not consider paragraphs and adds `<br />` tags also within `<ul>`s (which is not valid) 2. This does neither correct `<ul>`s within `<p>` tags, nor corrects `<br />` tags within `<ul>`s. This behavior is the same even when I use `doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;`

Comment: can you provide a sample of the input and output?  It should remove the invalid <br />'s added by the replace...

Comment: For the input, see above, and also note the newlines that are not marked with `<br>`s or `<p>`s. Therefore the newlines are not considered in the target tool. I will update my post to show the target output