# remove line breaks and white spaces

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)

hi I have an `textarea` which anyone can enter text, where they can put line breaks inside the text area.

How can I remove the line breaks created by pressing the enter key? can either be in c# or javascript.

Comment: Could the answer to this question be helpful? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c

Comment: @Scozzard, that's just what I need, thanks. i think I didn't search too much in SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
text.replace(/\s*/g," ")
```

This will collapse all contigious whitespace into a single space.

Comment: /\s*/g will match any white space, not just line breaks, I think what is wanted is: text.replace(/[\n\r\f]/g, ' ') which will replace all new line, return, and form feed characters with a space.

Comment: I was replying to the title not the question I guess. The question only asks about line breaks but the title mentions whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to simply ban the use of the enter key in the textarea in the first place, which can be done with event handlers (onKeyPress, for example)

Comment: that can't be done since i'm keeping 2 kinds of data, the formatted data which they need to press enter and others, and all text data.