# C# String issue

Tags: c#

I have a constant string as shown below

```
const String GetSQL = @"select
            id
        from
            emp

        ";
```

When I try to use the same in a method the value for the GetSQL is with the linebreaks 
i.e. select \r\n id\r\n etc.

How can I get it in one line without those breaks

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c)

Comment: Why do you want to declare the statement in that format?  Why don't you want line breaks in the end result?  Let us know what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't modify the constant value itself (as in put in all on one line in the code), this will show you how to replace the line breaks:

[Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c)

```
line = line.Replace(Environment.Newline, String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 5):

Is there some reason not to use: `SELECT id FROM emp` all on one line?

Comment: To learn the answers, one must know the correct questions to ask. 

Or in this case, leave it up to SO to give you the answer to your REAL problem.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

1. **Get rid of the line breaks, and format the SQL onto a single line.** This works well for a simple SQL query, but can get cumbersome if the SQL is large and complex.
2. **Programmatically remove the breaks using `string.Replace("\n"," ")`.** This can work well, but can be fragile - especially if you rewrite a single-line statement into a multi-line statement later.
3. **Don't put the string directly in your code, but read it from a resource or file.** This can allow you to better organize your SQL queries, but you may still need to remove undesired breaks (using replace as above).
4. **Use a stored-procedure to avoid embedding the SQL directly in your code to begin with.** It's a best practice, but it can require more significant changes to your code, and may not always be possible (for example, department policies may prohibit it).

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it without line breaks.  You can still put it on different lines using concatenation.

```
const string sql = "SELECT"
                 + "     id"
                 + " FROM"
                 + "     emp";
```

Answer (score 0):

programmatically remove the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you declare it as:

```
const String GetSQL = "select id from emp";
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Your String".Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")
```

or just

```
"Your String".Replace(Environment.Newline, "replacement text")
```