# How to eliminate ALL line breaks in string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, newline

I have a need to get rid of all line breaks that appear in my strings (coming from db).
I do it using code below:

```
value.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")
```

I can see that there's at least one character acting like line ending that survived it. The char code is [8232](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).

It's very lame of me, but I must say this is the first time I have a pleasure of seeing this char. It's obvious that I can just replace this char directly, but I was thinking about extending my current approach (based on replacing combinations of "\r" and "\n") to something much more solid, so it would not only include the '8232' char but also all others not-found-by-me yet.

Do you have a bullet-proof approach for such a problem?

EDIT#1:

It seems to me that there are several possible solutions:

1. use Regex.Replace
2. remove all chars if it's IsSeparator or IsControl
3. replace with " " if it's IsWhiteSpace
4. create a list of all possible line endings ( "\r\n", "\r", "\n",LF ,VT, FF, CR, CR+LF, NEL, LS, PS) and just replace them with empty string. It's a lot of replaces.

I would say that the best results will be after applying 1st and 4th approaches but I cannot decide which will be faster. Which one do you think is the most complete one?

EDIT#2

I posted anwer below.

Comment: For what it's worth, the character you're running into is U+2028, 'LINE SEPARATOR'. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Comment: I have deleted my answer but what about the following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c

Comment: It just asks about line breaks, not about special cases of them. In the context of this old question, the answer is correct, because the OP obviously doesn't care about such special cases, otherwise he would have mentioned them.

Comment: thanks for the explanation 
I have never got -3 in less than 1 minute. is there a badge for that? :-)))

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Below is the extension method solving my problem. LineSeparator and ParagraphEnding can be of course defined somewhere else, as static values etc.

```
public static string RemoveLineEndings(this string value)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    string lineSeparator = ((char) 0x2028).ToString();
    string paragraphSeparator = ((char)0x2029).ToString();

    return value.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)
                .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
                .Replace("\r", string.Empty)
                .Replace(lineSeparator, string.Empty)
                .Replace(paragraphSeparator, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: this miss only one offending char I have in my strings :  \f Formfeed

Comment: I used it successfully to solve problems during csv file creation. Some strings in it were with line separators and it  was a cause of incorrect lines arrangement. With the code above I solved the problem.

Comment: This is great. Thank you +1

Answer (score 25):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode), there are numerous line terminators you may need to handle (including this one you mention).

> LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
>    VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
>    FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
>    CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
>    CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
>    NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
>    LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
>    PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029

Comment: In regex form: `Regex.Replace(str, @"[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u2028\u2029\u0085]+", String.Empty)`

Answer (score 13):

8232 (0x2028) and 8233 (0x2029) are the only other ones you might want to eliminate.  See the documentation for [char.IsSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf.aspx).

Comment: Well, no -- what's "already implemented in the language" doesn't actually solve the original problem. Read the docs for char.IsSeparator -- it *won't* return true for the "normal" newline characters, because Unicode classifies those as "control characters".

Comment: @Joe - yes, but I was showing the OP that there *is* an official list of what character points he wants to get rid of, and it's in the documentation.

Comment: I think he meant just to look at the documentation, not to actually use `char.IsSeparator`.

Answer (score 11):

Props to Yossarian on this one, I think he's right.  Replace all whitespace with a single space:

```
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Uh... won't that insert spaces everywhere? As that not only matches all whitespace, it also matches the empty string. You'd want to use `"\s+"` instead.

Comment: Yes, `"\s*"` will match at every character, and insert a space after each one. Great if you're coding a spiffy Geocities site for 1995!

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend removing ALL the whitespace (char.IsWhitespace), and replacing it with single space.. IsWhiteSpace takes care of all weird unicode whitespaces.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `string.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")` ?  That usually gets a lot of them for me.

Comment: I've read somewhere here that it doesn't cover ALL situations.

Comment: it definitely doesn't cover ALL situations, just tested it.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first attempt at this, but I think this will do what you want....

```
var controlChars = from c in value.ToCharArray() where Char.IsControl(c) select c;
foreach (char c in controlChars)  
   value = value.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
```

Also, see this link for details on other methods you can use: [Char Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.char_methods%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Slightly shorter:
`value = new string(value.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray())`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h.aspx

You wil lhave to play around and build a REGEX expression that works for you. But here's the skeleton...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

        StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();
        txt.Append("Hello \n\n\r\t\t");
        txt.Append( Convert.ToChar(8232));

        System.Console.WriteLine("Original: <" + txt.ToString() + ">");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Cleaned: <" + CleanInput(txt.ToString()) + ">");

        System.Console.Read();

    }

    static string CleanInput(string strIn)
    {
        // Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
        return Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", ""); 
    }
```

Comment: I've tried all the other solutions and finally this is the only solution that working for me with : Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", ""), thank you @BBC

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 8232 is unicode, you can do this:

```
value.Replace("\u2028", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

personally i'd go with

```
    public static String RemoveLineEndings(this String text)
    {
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(text, i))
                newText.Append(text[i]);
        }
        return newText.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've a string say "theString" then
 use the method Replace and give it the arguments shown below:

`theString = theString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quick solutions with .NET regex:

- To remove any whitespace from a string: `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", "");` (`\s` matches any Unicode whitespace chars)
- To remove all whitespace BUT CR and LF: `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\s-[\r\n]]+", "");` (`[\s-[\r\n]]` is a character class containing a subtraction construct, it matches any whitespace but CR and LF)
- To remove any vertical whitespace, subtract `\p{Zs}` (any horizontal whitespace but tab) and `\t` (tab) from `\s`: `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]+", "");`.

Wrapping the last one into an extension method:

```
public static string RemoveLineEndings(this string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]+", "");
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%5D%2B&i=I%20have%0D%0Aa%20need%20%0D%0Ato%20get%20rid%20of%20all%20line%20%0D%0Abreaks%20that%20appear%20%0D%0Ain%20my%20strings%20%28coming%20from%20db%0D%0A%29.&r=).