# Remove Double LineBreak from RichTextBox to String

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, C#, WPF, XAML.

I copy the text from a `RichTextBox` to a `string` and remove any `LineBreaks`.

A `LineBreak` occurs if you press `Shift`+`Enter`. But just `Enter` causes a `Double LineBreak`.

Any text after the `Double LineBreak` gets cut off from `TextRange` and copying to the `string`.

What is this `Double LineBreak` and how do I remove it?

[image: richtextbox linebreak]

---

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbMessage" Margin="10,10,10,50" />
```

---

**C#**

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

// Get RichTextBox TextRange Method
//
public String MessageRichTextBox()
{
    rtbMessage.Document = new FlowDocument(p);

    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentStart,
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    return textRange.Text;
}


// RichTextBox to String
// Remove LineBreaks
//
string message = MessageRichTextBox().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

---

**Removal I have tried:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750310/6806643

```
Regex.Replace(MessageRichTextBox(), @"[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u2028\u2029\u0085]+", string.Empty);

.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
.Replace("\n", "")
.Replace("\r\n", "")
.Replace("\u2028", "")
.Replace("\u000A", "")
.Replace("\u000B", "")
.Replace("\u000C", "")
.Replace("\u000D", "")
.Replace("\u0085", "")
.Replace("\u2028", "")
.Replace("\u2029", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve `RichTextBox` text like this

```
public String MessageRichTextBox()
{
    rtbMessage.Document = new FlowDocument(p);
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentStart,
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentEnd
    );
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

you modify the content of the `rtbMessage`, so you get the wrong content. I assume you somehow reference the 1st paragraph of the document in `p` and truncate the document to the 1st paragraph right there. Try to remove the line `rtbMessage.Document = new FlowDocument(p);` and see if it works for you?

When user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> there is no double-`LineBreak` being inserted, but a new `Paragraph` is created. You can verify it by trying to place the caret to a presumably empty line there - if it's a double line break, there should be an empty line and the caret can be positioned on it.

Anyway, the document on your screenshot should have 2 paragraph blocks like this:

- Paragraph 1: "Hello, world."
- Paragraph 2: "This is a test.<LineBreak/>Example."

Hence my assumption is that when you re-create a document trying to retrieve its content as a text, you only retain the 1st paragraph there and discard the rest.