# C# remove extra carriage returns from Stream

Tags: c#, stream

Im reading file in as a stream: `Stream fin = File.OpenRead(FilePath);`
Is there any way how i would be able to find and remove all carriage returns from that file stream?

EDIT: The goal is to remove single carriage-returns `\r` and leave the carriage returns what are with newline `"\r\n"` intact.

Example file:

```
The key backed up in this file is:\r
\r\n
pub   2048R/65079BB4 2011-08-01\r
\r\n
      Key fingerprint = 2342334234\r
\r\n
uid                  test\r
\r\n
sub   2048R/0B917D1C 2011-08-01\r
```

And the result should look like:

```
The key backed up in this file is:
\r\n
pub   2048R/65079BB4 2011-08-01
\r\n
      Key fingerprint = 2342334234
\r\n
uid                  test
\r\n
sub   2048R/0B917D1C 2011-08-01
```

EDIT2: The final solution what is working looks like this:

```
    static private Stream RemoveExtraCarriageReturns(Stream streamIn)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        string key = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string final = key.Replace("\r\r", "\r");
        byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(final);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
        return stream;
    }
```

I take in the `Stream` use `StreamReader` to read it into a string, then remove the extra carriage-return and write it back to a `Stream`.
Does my code look ok or should i do something differently?

Comment: Looks fine although you should probably set the Position of the return stream to zero within the method for API neatness. Good solution for small files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your sample text, the following will remove your single 'r' instances:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

text = text.Replace("\r\r", "\r");

File.WriteAllText(FilePath + ".modified", text);
```

Comment: This might not be an issue but if given the string `"\r\r\r"` the result would still be `"\r\r"`. You'd have to do the replace over and over until you get the same string back as you made the replace on.

Comment: @aL3891 Agreed, but from the sample text this would not occur.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
string final = string.Join("", File.ReadLines(path));
```

? This reads line-by-line, then re-combines without any separator.

Answer (score 0):

[Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c)

The above has the answer. You could read in the file into a string and then remove the line breaks.

Comment: I think he wants to remove them directly from the stream, but Yeah it would be better to just remove them once read into a stream.

Comment: Yes, reading file into a string is my last option. Just wanted to know if there a way to do it right in the stream.