# .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") works on localhost but not when I upload my website to host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have no idea why is that. Here is my code and it works perfectly when I try it on localhost but when I upload my website my text has no `<br />`'s. Why this could happen? And how can I fix this issue with new lines? (`white-space: pre-line;` is not a solution for me, it is not working on IE6 and it is messing with my styles)

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Body)
.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))<br />
```

Comment: Is the definition of `Environment.NewLine` the same in both places?

Comment: When dealing with web input I always replace `\n` vs using Environment.NewLine as different browsers could send `\r\n` or `\n` but they all send at least `\n`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As BuildStarted mentioned in the comments, the browsers might either send `\r\n` or `\n`, which will break, if you use `Environment.NewLine` - and I don't think asp.net will fix that up before running your code.

I'd suggest you use a regular expression to replace linebreaks instead: `"\\r?\\n"` This should match both cases (I don't expect any browser to actually use '\r' only).

Answer (score 37):

I believe this answer is best:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196219/550975

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot has happened since IE6 *(thank god!)* so I would just like mention the CSS solution to the problem.

In your C#:

```
ViewBag.StringText = "some text" + Environment.NewLine + "more text in a new line";
```

In your CSS:

```
.newlines { 
  white-space:pre-line; 
}
```

In your Razor:

```
<div class="newlines">@ViewBag.StringText</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Environment.NewLine`, try this:

```
someString.Replace(@"\r\n", "<br/>");
```