# Enable HTML Tag inside DB Query String

Tags: c#, html, sql, string

I have a database query that displays a string:

```
db.query.record
```

> "This is a string"

I want the string to be read:

> "This
> is
> a
> string"

the code i used was `db.query.record.replace(" ", "<br />")` and the results i got were:

> "This`<br>`is`<br>`a`<br>`string"

What i understand is, the `replace` syntax is storing the html tag in the database string before it is read. After it is read, anything inside the string is displayed just as it is stored (as a string). I need the html to bypass the string, and fetch the html tag, and perform the action.

Suggestions, ideas? I've tried everything... and all results i've tried were done to the text string... and not to the actual html. Be mindful that i dont need this to affect the entire document, just the queried data. I need it to be multi-line, because the data is making my page disorganized (text vary in lengths and size)

If there are any answers that cover the topic `Literals` or `LiteralsControl` can you please include extra details, cause either i dont understand enough or it, or i was doing it wrong. Internet queries does not provide enough understanding for me.

I want to perform the complete opposite of this request: [overflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005264/escape-text-for-html?lq=1)

Comment: This probably has more to do with asp.net html-encoding the string _after_ reading it from the database than anything the db or replace() method is doing. How does this string get from the db to the page?

Comment: you might have a point, i tried playing with Encode/Decode, but all it did really was turn `<` to `lt&r;` or something like that... i'm not sure i understand you question, but i think the answer you're looking for is something like: `<h3>db.query.record.replace(" ", "<br />")</h3>`. (it's a name/title, and i want it to be multi-line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was from another overflow question: [.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") works on localhost but not when I upload my website to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084173/replaceenvironment-newline-br-works-on-localhost-but-not-when-i-upload)

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Body)
.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))<br />
```

i simply changed out `Model.Body` with `db.query.record` and `Environment.NewLine` with `" "`. Apperently, that did the trick. What i discovered was that encoding/decoding the string was my issue, but it just wasnt applying at the right stage. It was supposed to be done a period after it was compiled, but before it was read (by the browser). I'm not sure, something like that... Anyways, i understand what i did wrong, and i figured it out. Thanks to those that submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I know I've personally had trouble with this, but on a web page. So, I'm assuming you're trying to add content to your page.

If you're adding the text to, let's say, a `<p>` tag, you'll need to set the text via `.innerHTML` as opposed to `.innerText`.

Example:

HTML:

`<p id='myP' runat='server'>Test</p>`

VB:
`myP.innerHTML = db.query.record.replace(" ", "<br />");`

Or
`myP.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(db.query.record.replace(" ", "<br />")));`

Comment: uhh, there are a few things that concern me with this response. I'm using ASP.NET not ASP Classic, and i'm querying data from database, so i'd need to apply an `id` to multiple tags, and having the `Controls` syntax grab each `id` might cause confusion in the script. i gave it a shot though, gave me an error. tried attaching the `id=` attribute to the database row id, and the `row.id.Controls` gave me and error, said it couldnt apply to integers.

Comment: I'm sorry, my confusion, allow me to rephrase. My files are saved in `.cshtml` format versus `.aspx` format. The `runat='server'` doesnt do anything for me. But the error i mentioned in previous post, i cant think of a work-around.

Comment: The code I posted is for ASP.NET, I apologize as I'm used to .NET not C#. I've also never used a lot of the data controls. My guess is that data controls are handled by the server similarly to SQL queries and the server generates generic controls such as `<table/>` automatically. I might suggest looking into another method for displaying your data. OR you could try some really fancy CSS and/or JavaScript. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224062/html-change-line-break-trigger