# Dump text to file with line breaks

Tags: c#, file-io, textbox, line, dump

```
private void btnDump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\TestFile.txt"))
    {
        // Add some text to the file.
        sw.WriteLine(txtChange.Text);
    }
}
```

This dumps the text of txtChange to a text file. txtChange is a Rich text box and has line breaks (new lines) in it.

When the user clicks the Dump button all the text is Dumped but not on new lines.

E.g. txtChange looks like

```
1
2
3
4
```

dumping the text looks like `1234`

**How do i format the dumping of the text so that the text is on new lines?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`Lines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property instead:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\TestFile.txt", txtChange.Lines);
```

You don't really need to use a stream since the `File` class contains these static convenience methods - short and to the point.

Above will replace any existing content with the text lines contained in your text box `txtChange`. If you want to *append* content use the appropriately named `File.AppendAllLines()` instead.

Comment: @hungryMind: That sound logical to me, too, but looking at `WriteLine` in reflector I don't think it's doing any line collapsing.

Comment: @BrokenGlass This works fine, I have just tried adding another text box contents but this overwrites the text taken from txtChange, Do you know the command to add text ('copying' over the new lines as well)?

Comment: @Dan1676: Added to my answer - check out the `File` class on msdn for more convenience methods.

Answer (score 4):

just add a newline char:

```
private void btnDump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\TestFile.txt"))
    {
        // Add some text to the file.
        sw.WriteLine(txtChange.Text + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: this would only add a single line break at the end

Answer (score 1):

If it contains \r's as you mentioned, you should try this

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\TestFile.txt"))
{
    // Add some text to the file.
    sw.WriteLine(txtChange.Text.Replace("\r", "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
private void btnDump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\TestFile.txt"))
     {
         // Add some text to the file.
         sw.WriteLine(txtChange.Text + Environment.NewLine);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp) and replace all linebreaks so it matches Windows Standard.

take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations for linbreak definitions.