# Take a single line of string from a richTextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

I'm sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find the answer which fit my needs

I have a richTextBox in c# and I want to get a continuous string of text of the contents

The problem is .Text will get something like:

First line \n Second  Line \n Third Line

and what I need is:

First line Second Line Third Line

I don't want to directly parse the \n as it might be relevant to the text I'm retrieving but I don't want it added based on the lines of the richTextBox

Any ideas? Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, would this work for you?

```
string text = richTextBox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

The alternative could be to use the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196219/187697).

```
string text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox.Text, @"\r\n?|\n", " ");
```

Comment: its close, but that returns:

First Line\Second Line\Third Line

Comment: You can replace with a `space` instead of an empty string (I've updated the answer). Or do you mean there are actual backslashes in the output?

Comment: Yes there are slashes in the output, although maybe thats an error in judgement by reading the VS Locals window?

Comment: Possibly but I can't test it at the moment. However, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8196219/187697) uses a regex to remove the new lines so you can try that to see if that's the issue. I've updated my answer to include that.