# Replace wordwrap of a Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can I replace the line break of a textbox (multiline-box) by the html's `<br>`?

This is my code:

```
string output = tb_Notizen.Text.Replace("\\r\\n", "<br>");
```

Whats wrong here?

I already tried it with `\r\n` but it didn't worked too...

Comment: I don't know, what *is* wrong? What "didn't worked"? Please post more example input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Maybe try Google first: [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try with [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because `\r` and `\n` are platform dependant.

> \n is Unix, \r is Mac, \r\n is Windows

Environment.NewLine would return any of the above based on the operating system.

```
string output = tb_Notizen.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");
```