# C# Deserialize html inside json property

Tags: c#, html, deserialization

How can I decode with console application a html string inside json property like this?:

```
{
    "type":"text",
    "html":"\n\n\n <div class=\"class\">\n          <ul>\n\n\n  <li class=\"class1\">\n\n\n\n\n\n<a href=\"url\" class=\"class2\"   title='title'  \n >\n    title\n</a>\n\n  ..."
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Json.Net for deserialization. This can be deserialized to a Dictionary<string,string>

Comment: Yes I done it using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ResponseJson>(source); but the html text it's always with \n \" etc.. :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, see [Online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRpT05) - But I guess you are getting confused by the debugger view of the variable content and that is always an escaped version

Comment: Yes I am, sorry that work it **thankssss!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class:

```
public class JsonClass
{
public string type{get;set;}
public string html{get;set;}
}
```

Add a reference to Newtonsoft (
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Next, deserialize the content:

```
string json = @"{
     //your json
}";
var response = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(json);

var html = response.html;
```

The html variable will contain the results

Comment: sorry I think that I explanated bad my problem :( ; when i deserialize that with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(json); the html text is  not deserialized and contain charapter like \n \" etc..

Comment: Hello have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp please mark as  answer if this solves your problem