# How to encode simple text to HTML, C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to format a user input (multi row) in a application. The text that's returned could be like this:

```
"This is \r\na test\r\nwith rowbreaks"
```

This later is sent by email and the text just formats like this:

```
"This is a test with rowbreaks"
```

How can I format this to HTML? I've tried HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, but that returns just the same with \r\n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `<br />` tags for HTML linebreaks, all whitespace gets replaced by spaces. You can easily do this manually:

```
var text = "This is \r\na test\r\nwith rowbreaks";
var htmlText = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Or using other replacement methods as explained in:
[Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, that was simple :)