# How to preserve newline wrapping via SMTP where the email body needs to support HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, smtpclient

So I'm building an auto-emailing script that will send out receipts to employees once they log an issue, the email needs to allow `HTML`.

However, when I pull the description out of the database and display it on the front end (`asp:textbox`) of the `.aspx page` it displays with new line characters, formatted properly but when I send the description via SMTP to recipients the line breaks (newline characters) don't wrap the text to the new line.

E.g:
Example string: "Bob is a human,\n and he likes basketball"
In `asp:textbox` controls it renders properly but when sent via the email it doesn't.

What's the crack with that? Do I need to replace the `\n` with `HTML` breaks as they come through or can you preserve them?

Here's the basic idea of what the script is:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.outlook.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(serverEmail, serverEmailAuthToken);

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(serverEmail, recipient, "Tasket Report Number: "
                                 + tasketTitle + " has been received.",
                                 "Tasket Report Number: " + tasketTitle + "<br/>"
                                 + "Problem Domain: " + domain + "<br/>"
                                 + "Report Type: " + type + "<br/>"
                                 + "Report Area: " + area + "<br/>"
                                 + "Description: " + description
                                 + "<br/>");
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: "Do I need to replace the \n with HTML breaks as they come through or can you preserve them?" Indeed, you are sending HTML, and `\n` is not a bnreaking line in that language.

Comment: For a clean and simple solution [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238020/9269688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is whitespace to HTML renderers.

You need to convert the newlines to `<br />` tags, or paragraphs, in order to render as newlines in an HTML mail body.

And you should make sure that the actual text is `HtmlEncode`d. If you don't, user input could be used to inject markup into the mail.

Time-tested set of utility functions, I hereby declare thee open source:

```
public string enc(string s)
{
    return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);
}

/// <summary>
/// HTML-encodes a string after replacing its newlines with br tags
/// </summary>
public string enc_br(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return s;
    var lines = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (lines.Length == 1)
        return enc(lines[0]);
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
        {
            lines[i] = enc(lines[i]);
        }
        return String.Join("<br />", lines);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
...  + "Problem Domain: " + enc_br(domain) + "<br/>"
```

Consider using `String.Format`, or, if you are on a sufficiently recent .NET version, string interpolation: it will improve readability of your composition greatly.

Comment: I had a feeling it would have to be done in a fashion similar to this - nice solution here.