# How to remove a line break character from a field in a text file

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# so I apologize for any trashy code.

I am trying to use StreamWriter.Write/WriteLine to either write a new line or write two consecutive lines as one line to a file.

I have a text file with 12 million rows that has a line break character that occurs in a certain field in hundreds of rows, causing the row to be split into two.  Here's a simplified example:

```
012345, District 1, John Smith, Active\n
987624, District 2\n
, Jane Doe, Inactive\n
583940, District 3, Bobby Roberts, Active\n
```

I'm using StreamReader and a while loop to read through each line and replace the errant line breaks, then write each line to a new file.  I thought I could use `Write()` to write the offending line ("987624, District 2") without a line break at the end and `WriteLine()` to add the next line to the offending line.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("sourcefile.txt"))
        using (StreamWriter swp = new StreamWriter("processedfile.txt", append: true))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Length < 25 && Char.IsDigit(line, 0))
                {
                    swp.Write(line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
                }
                else
                {
                    swp.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Expected result:

```
012345, District 1, John Smith, Active
987624, District 2, Jane Doe, Inactive
583940, District 3, Bobby Roberts, Active
```

Actual result:

```
012345, District 1, John Smith, Active
987624, District 2
, Jane Doe, Inactive
583940, District 3, Bobby Roberts, Active
```

I can't do anything about how the file comes, it's just my responsibility to fix it.

Comment: That won't work. `string.Write()` simply writes content in one line, but if the content has a new line, it will still go into a second line.

Comment: Try replacing "\\n"

Comment: A line won't contain a linebreak in the middle, since that's the definition of the end of the line...sounds like you have a malformed document and will have to parse it some other way, like `if (line.StartsWith(',')) // append this line to the previous one`

Comment: "Fix your dataset," should never be answered with "I can't do anything."  Otherwise, you risk additional future issues as the dataset becomes more complex and contains other fields/data that trip up your attempt to clean it.

Comment: Try `swp.WriteLine(line.Replace("\\n", "");` You still want WriteLine so a line break is added to the end of the whole line. As mentioned above, `Enviornment.NewLine()` is `\r\n` so try just `\n`

Comment: please try this
`string removedBreaks = Line.Replace("\r\n", replaceWith).Replace("\n", replaceWith).Replace("\r", replaceWith);`    ---found from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/238016/6923146

Comment: Your code has an error : if (line.Length < 25 && Char.IsDigit(line, 0))  Should be : if (line.Length < 25 && Char.IsDigit(line, line.Length - 1))

Comment: @jdweng No, it's the digit at the beginning of a real line, not a digit-in-text at an incorrect line break, that OP wants to test, to find the initial part. The fact that "District 2" ends in a digit is coincidence.

Comment: You need to test for the line not to end in a digit for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same `if` condition you use (assuming you're certain that there won't be exceptions), but in case it's true, read an additional line and concatenate the two.

```
var file = @"input.txt";
var output = @"output.txt";
var line = string.Empty;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(output))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Length < 25 && Char.IsDigit(line, 0))
            {
                var line2 = sr.ReadLine();
                line += line2;
            }
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Input file:

> 012345, District 1, John Smith, Active
>
> 987624, District 2
>
> , Jane Doe, Inactive
>
> 583940, District 3, Bobby Roberts, Active

Output file:

> 012345, District 1, John Smith, Active
>
> 987624, District 2, Jane Doe, Inactive
>
> 583940, District 3, Bobby Roberts, Active

Comment: I think you have nailed it, unless there are no more than one straw _\n_ to break the line

Comment: Agreed. The OP doesn't specify whether it can have different types/number of line breaks, so this comes with the caveat that this will only work for the given example.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Fortunately, there's only one occurrence in each line and it always occurs in the same field.  Thanks.