# Using command line argument in debug mode has issues in VS2022 when referencing paths, how to remedy?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have an application that takes command line arguments.  One of the arguments is an argument called "exepath".  In order to test certain elements I created a command line argument for the debugger in the Launch Profile:

[image]

The exepath is `/exepath="C:\Sandbox\scheduling-services\Projects\LSS.Host\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\LSS.Host.exe"`

How ever when I put a breakpoint in the code the arguments shows as this:

[image]

Notice that between Debug and net6.0 there is only one backslash(eg: Debug\net6.0...) instead of 2(eg: Debug\\net6.0...).  When I click view this causes it to be interpreted as a newline:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this? And if so were you able to find a work around?

This causes an issue and seems to be a bug.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is known issue and to be fixed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Debug-Launch-Profile-Command-Line-Argume/10025387?space=8&q=%5Cn

Comment: @PawełŁukasik - for some reason the link results in a message "We were unable to get this feedback item. " when I click on it.

Comment: Try searching for "Debug Launch Profile Command Line Arguments Cannot Pass "\n" (i.e. a path like "Debug\net6.0") Without Seeing "\n" as New Line" issue

Comment: One of my teammates found it for me... for some reason I couldnt get to it with my work account.  Yeah, one of the work arounds was to use a capital N, however that doesnt work wiith what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be solved in VS (community) 2022.
I print the command line arguments and it shows:
/exepath=C:\Sandbox\scheduling-services\Projects\LSS.Host\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\LSS.Host.exe.

Worst case you can replace the 'newline' in the corrupted string by a backslash: [Replace Line Breaks in a String C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)