# Copy text without new line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two text mesh pros and I am trying to copy from one to another. The first text mesh pro looks like this:

```
Computer.
CPU, GPU, HDD.
Graphics Card Nvidia.
```

Now I want to copy this to my second text mesh pro but without new lines. That is, the final text should be:

```
Computer. CPU, GPU, HDD. Graphics Card Nvidia.
```

How do I do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class CopyMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI text1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI text2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        text2.text = text1.text;
    }
```

Comment: you can replace new line as any other text with whatever you want ... you can even split by new line and join with whatever you want ... Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace newlines with blank or whitespace like this:

```
text2.text = text1.text.Replace("\n","");;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace new line with a blank. Take a look at [What would be the fastest way to remove Newlines from a String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-remove-newlines-from-a-string-in-c)

in your case this would be something like this

```
text2.text = text1.text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```